# React Native: Module JSTimers in not a registered callable module

Tags: react-native

As the title says, i'm getting the error

```
Uncaught Error: JSTimers is not a registered callable module (calling callTimers)
```

I can't find mention of the error anywhere else, and i don't know where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have changed the react-native version. Something may be left in the build process.

Android,

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```

And

```
react-native run-android
```

Try something like this.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I ran my emulator with proxy:

> emulator -avd Nexus_6_API_23 -http-proxy 10.234.51.15:8888

But I forgot to start my proxy server. When I started the proxy, the app back to work.